# What NuGet components does MyGet build on top of?

Tags: nuget, myget

The NuGet system consists of NuGet.Core, NuGet.exe, NuGet.Server, NuGet.org(the official gallery). Which of these components does MyGet extend?

Answer (score 0):

We are a custom gallery (using NuGet.Core under the hood).